# Подскажите, нужны ли запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Доставим свежие продукты, когда удобно, лично в руки.

Answer (score 2):

Возможен такой вариант:

Доставим свежие продукты: когда удобно, лично в руки!

Здесь сочетание "когда удобно" можно рассматривать не только как придаточное, но и как обстоятельство. Или считать, что придаточное  находится в однородных отношениях со вторым обстоятельством.

Это реклама, фраза должна быть выразительной.

Answer (score 0):

Вы правильно расставили запятые.